# Can this ripples effect be replicated in Blender 3?

Tags: modifiers, physics

I have been trying to replicate [this great trick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBWaARrOiyE&t=202s) in a newer project.

It worked perfectly fine in earlier versions of Blender, but unfortunately doesn't seem to work anymore in 3.1.

Can this easy ripples effect be replicated, or is there another simple way of creating ripples?

Comment: Perhaps it uses some addon that is out of date.

Comment: It seems relatively to the native version of blender and only uses Wave modifier, Dynamic Paint and that's it. See if you can replicate it in 3.1 and how, I would be interested - thanks

Comment: Still seems to work you likely missed a step.

Comment: @Ratt as soon as I add the waves modifier the plane bounces up and down and looks like a sphere cut in half

Comment: It's working for me too, can you add a gif or a blender file with the problem to your question? .blend preferred.

Comment: @MicroMachine when you follow the tutorial Gleb zero's out the initial wave height. you only get the ripples from the dynamic paint after.

Comment: @Ratt At 1:10 into it "if you press play" his waves create many concentric ripples around the origin of the object. [This is what you get](https://imgur.com/a/IlLMWUd)  if you follow the same steps - new plane, subdivide, add modifier - in Blender 3.1

Comment: I think the plane in the video was scaled up and then had it's scale applied before the recording started.

Comment: I think it's too straightforward to actually write up, but the way I'd try to approach this is to have a plane for each drop with the procedural animation of ripples and some transparency, then render overlapping ripples as a bump information, and then use that animation to control the texture of water.

Answer (score 3):

Settings for confirmation:

Objects:
1 plane ~100,000 faces
1 uv sphere

modifier stack on plane:

[image: ![](file:///C:\blender%20forum%20questions\blender%20stack%20exchange\rain%20ripples.png)]

physics dynamic paint

[image: ![](file:///C:\blender%20forum%20questions\blender%20stack%20exchange\dynamic%20paint.png)]

sphere particle system

[image: ![](file:///C:\blender%20forum%20questions\blender%20stack%20exchange\sphere%20particle%20system.png)]

sphere dynamic paint

[image: ![](file:///C:\blender%20forum%20questions\blender%20stack%20exchange\sphere%20dynamic%20paint.png)]

[image: ![](rain%20ripples.gif)]